# problem with raster calculator syntax

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, syntax

I am trying to build a raster representing the output from a logistic regression model. i keep getting syntax errors. heres the script:

-2.41-(15.97 * "Topographic_Predictors\wadem10m_annsolrad") - (9.56*("Topographic_Predictors\wadem10m_annsolrad"^2))+(.01*"Topographic_Predictors\wadem10m_slope")-(11.25"Topographic_Predictors\TPI\wadem10_tpi20")-(12.55*("Topographic_Predictors\TPI\wadem10_tpi20"^2))

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What is the precise error that you are receiving?

Comment: Regardless of the software, there are obvious typographical errors. For instance, "11.25" has been concatenated to a string expression--no raster calculator will know what to make of that.  The first thing to do is fix them.  Even if you're successful, it would be wise to compute each sub-expression separately and review its results to check that you are getting what you expect.  That exercise will pinpoint any remaining problems.

Comment: you spotted it! it was just a missing* after the 11.25 and then it ran fine. thanks!